# What are lists in Swift, and how can I use subscripts with a list?

Tags: swift, subscript

*The Swift Programming Guide (Swift 5.1 Edition)* says that subscripts can be used to access members of “a collection, list, or sequence.” `Collection` and `Sequence` are defined protocols in Swift and are well documented. Do lists exist in Swift as a separate entity? If so, what is the syntax for a list subscript?

Comment: Would someone care to explain the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be better if *The Swift Programming Language* (the book) **didn't** say “ a collection, list, or sequence”. As you point out, Swift has standard `Collection` and `Sequence` types. It does **not** have any standard type named `List`.

The closest thing would be `Array`:

```
let words: Array<String> = ["Mark", "Cowan"]
// or words: [String]
let firstWord = words[0]
```

Comment: Thanks, @rob, but an array is both a collection and a sequence. How is a list different? Or is the passage I quoted simply misleading?

Comment: `Collection` inherits `Sequence`, so every type that conforms to `Collection` also conforms to `Sequence`. There is no type or protocol named `List` in the standard library, so the passage is misleading.